# Render custom icons in Dart comment

Tags: flutter, dart

I was wondering if there was a way to render custom icons in Dart comment, just as Material and Cupertino icons are.

To give a little bit of context, the project I'm currently working on uses [TablerIcons](https://tabler-icons.io/) and I wasn't able to find a package up to date and I was about to make one. So I was wondering if there is a way to display icons in Dart comment, the same way Material and Cupertino Icons are.

For example, with the icon 10k this piece of code is used:

```
<i class="material-icons md-36">10k</i> &#x2014; material icon named "10k"
```

which would give you something like this in vscode:

[image]

I tried different ways but couldn't make it work so I'm asking you guys if you have any ideas on how to do that, or if it's even possible.

Thanks.